# Gitlab Jenkins rebuild specific commit

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

Right now we do have a Jenkins Gitlab integration which is triggers Jenkins for the following events:

- Push
- Tag Push

Sporadically we are having issues in our Jenkins Pipeline, so we would like to rebuild a specific
commit.

Is there a easy way on how to achieve this? Actually I think it would be great to trigger a Jenkins Pipeline run if I could just add a comment to the commit in gitlab.

But when I tried to do that no Jenkins Job was scheduled. I have enabled 'Comments' in the gitlab Webhook configuration and the 'Comments' option in the 'Build Triggers' section of Jenkins.

Also if I test the webhook from gitlab nothing is happening on Jenkins (although a positive response from gitlab is reported '200').

Right now I have to amend and force push changes to get up to date builds, but I don't like to do that on master.